# Multisite: Can't Post or Create Categories

Tags: posts, multisite, subdomains

I created a multisite with two sub-sites. This is the structure:

> example.com - root
>
> ----- > example.com/site2
>
> ----- > example.com/site3

Everything works fine, except for posting on the root node/domain. I am unable to publish a post. When I try, I get an error message

> "Sorry, you are not allowed to edit this post."

I also cannot create categories. Trying to create one results in the following error:

> Could not insert term into the database.

The root site doesn't even have `Uncategorised` as a category.

I'm a Super Admin with privileged access to all the sites, including the root site. What am I missing here?

Comment: How did you create your multisite install? Have you conducted the process of elimination debugging routine to see if a plugin or theme is responsible?

Comment: @TomJNowell I installed manually by FTP. I didn't come across any problems during install. Yeah, could be a plugin. I can't think of anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Check out if you have proper user roles set for your user account in each site. To do so, open `wp-admin/network`, open **Sites**, and when you click **Edit** for each site, you can see users assigned and roles. There you can add your user to sites.

Comment: I'm a Super Admin with privileges to all sites including the root, but I still can't make changes. The root site doesn't even have the 'Uncategorised' category. Is that normal?

Comment: Maybe something was wrong during the installation. Did you installed network as new, or copied it (backup, restore)? I have seen some strange things related to networks, and without indept analysis of the database, I can't say more.

Comment: I installed it from scratch and it went pretty smoothly. I didn't come across any issue.